# Putting your e-mail on your resume

Tags: resume, email

I was passing my resume to a friend so he could pass it along to his company.  He was taking a look at it and gave me a list of things I should fix.  This was one of them:

*Get a Gmail or a custom domain like firstname@lastname.com or .pro. Yes we will filter out email by domain name.*

However, I didn't think this was a problem.  I use my e-mail which just contains my name (so nothing questionable), and it's a Hotmail account.  Is it really necessary to change it?  My  email just follows this format:

*firstname_lastname@hotmail.com*

I have been contacted by many companies with this same resume and email (Amazon, Microsoft, Palantir, Booz Allen, etc.).  I have also been given a handful of offers in the past 2+ years.  I really just wanted to confirm that either I was wrong in thinking my email is fine as it is or he's wrong (or his company's wrong) in thinking/working that way.

Comment: I wouldn't, as long as its clean and not abusive or offensive I would use it. Mine is myname@hotmail.com and I have never had a problem getting a job

Comment: @Marriott81 Same.  I've been getting offers with my same resume format for about 2+ years.  I'm not sure if it's just him being picky about it.  I feel that if his company *does* look away from common emails, then it just makes his company look pretentious.

Comment: @MohammadS. Not only that, but if they're filtering a bunch of big e-mail accounts then they're missing out on a LOT of applicants.

Comment: @MohammadS. as long as they can reach you I would still use it. Shall I put that as an answer for ya?

Comment: For what its worth, now that Hotmail has been rebranded you can request an Outlook.com email address alias

Comment: @n00b According to him, that's just as bad (or unprofessional).  Although most all my job emails were an Outlook email.

Comment: @MohammadS. Large Corporations use Outlook emails. If they are filtering those out, then they clearly are filtering out too many candidates. Clearly you have already proven him wrong by showing him that top companies did not filter out your resume simply based on your email domain (Hotmail).

Comment: It honestly boggles the mind to think that someone would judge an "@hotmail.com" email address "unprofessional" but think the same address "@gmail.com" was fine. Just out of curiosity, is this a Linux shop that might be populated by the "Micro$oft is the devil!" crowd?

Comment: @Carson63000 Actually, he does fit that category..

Comment: This stems from the fact that [many people seem to be biased towards Gmail or against the likes of hotmail](http://lifehacker.com/5447335/know-what-your-email-address-says-about-you) even though it's 100% baseless.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe putting your email address in your resume is a bad thing, unless it looks like `i_am_a_junkie@hotmail.com`. I think your friend's main point was that a Hotmail address might look less serious/professional to some potential hirer than a Gmail account or a custom domain.

For future references, Hotmail (and probably many other mail service provider) allows you to define an alias to your email account. So if you do use a less serious email address (`i_eat_bananas@hotmail.com`) and do not wish to create a separate and more serious account, you can create a more serious alias and use this one in your resume or other professional correspondance.

Comment: firstname_lastname@hotmail.com is very professional.  His concern is near ridiculous though.  I've never heard it before.  I don't remember Amazon, Microsoft, Palantir, etc ever having an issue with contacting me when I passed my resume.

Comment: @MohammadS. I totally agree. I merely mentioned the less serious email address thing so that my answer would contain more information for future visitors ;)

Comment: I don't think that was my friend's main point though.  It is a clearly professional email.  I think there is something else he's suggesting/saying.   |=^/

Comment: Wife work in recruiting, and has seen things like "thuglife420@..., cottncndyflavrdnipples@...." on a resume.  She obviously passed on those candidates.  Great source of entertainment though!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a professional alias at the front, having a Hotmail domain should not be an issue. I disagree with Bill Leeper on that count. It's a valid source of a free email address. I do agree with him on the AOL address (not that it's your situation, but just to establish that there are common email service I wouldn't trust).

Of course, if your "Firstname.Lastname" is available on GMail, I'd advise picking it up. You can always set it up to forward your email to your Hotmail account, and it give you an option should you learn that there are recruiters who simply don't like Hotmail.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part the particular email choice doesn't make much of a difference.  However, I work in the technical field and if you are applying for a technical position it does make a difference.

Hotmail is a has been and if you are looking at technology jobs, employers like people who are innovative and run with current technology, or in some cases the very edge of technology.

Everything you put on your resume will come into consideration when I look it over, not just where you worked or where you went to school, but things like your email address are indicative of your choice in technology.

A gmail address is a good choice and easy enough to setup.

Be careful with the vanity email address.  Make sure it isn't something even remotely offensive.  I do know someone that had an offer pulled over a vanity email address.

Comment: I agree that it would be odd to see a hotmail account in an application for a technology job. Probably not bad enough to cost you the interview, though.

Comment: -1 for "These days a hotmail email is a joke". Recently Microsoft has rebranded and completely face lifted hotmail to Outlook online. It is fast, efficient and web 2.0, putting it right up there with Google in terms of usability and efficiency.

Comment: AOL have also been doing upgrading, although I don't use it for actual email just testing, their interface is quite modern.

Comment: The only warning sign I would get from "...@hotmail.com" is someone who hasn't updated their resume or their perspective on email for a long time. It's outlook.com these days.

Comment: It is similar to applying for a Social Media Expert role without having a Twitter account. For a technical role, I would also frown on a hotmail.com address, while you would get bonus points for using your proper domain (firstname@lastname.com).

Comment: +1. Microsoft ruined it's reputation. No Outlook or whatnot will fix that. Even Outlook is tied to Metro, which is again not a huge success. tl;dr: Just use gmail or register an own domain. (its cheap anyway.) You can then use that custom domain with Outlook.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with Outlook.com which all @hotmail emails use.  There isn't a single statement in this answer that isn't an personal opinion

Answer (score 0):

I have never personally heard of a company filter out Emails by domains although one way to prove initiative knowledge is to buy your own domain name. From what I have heard when there is a job seekers in particularly non-technical job seekers that have taken the time and effort to obtain their own domain name and email address for their own use instead of using a free email provider. Bear in mind that it is not always a necessity to actually develop the domain website, though it will look good if you actually add something on to your newly acquired site. You might as well use the space to your advantage and promote yourself.