# is it better to use gmail or email@mydomain.com in a CV?

Tags: resume, email

Is it a better idea to use my `gmail` or `me@mydomain.com` in a resume? I have a spooky domain name, similar to [codinghorror.com](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/), it's about programming and stuff too, and it is very well designed, it doesn't look spammy. And I am applying for a programming job, if it matters.

What email to use?

Let me put it like this:

is `Jeff@codinghorror.com` better or worst than `Jeffatwood@gmail.com`?

Comment: Also http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/19768/putting-your-e-mail-on-your-resume

Comment: @JoeStrazzere neither of those links say anything about your personal domain name

Comment: @SeanDuggan please read my comment

Comment: is "Putting your e-mail on your resume" similar to my question? I can't see similarities, the guy asking about his hotmail and whether he should get a gmail... maybe i just can't see it, nevermind

Comment: @gnat Hey I know that you edited my question to remove my domain because we're not advertising here and you vote me down because of that, but I didn't want to put it in the first place, you have enough rep to see the original question, Sean requeseted that I add these stuff

Comment: @JoeStrazzere so in general it is worse, right?

Comment: was this not literally on the front page of this stack? like 4 or 5 down?

Comment: stuff like that looks _very_ slippery in question text; it seems to be more appropriate in comments. See. I copy it here for anyone who really needs it: " my website is scarycode.com, it's down currently, I'm moving hosting. and my gmail is `myname@gmail.com`"

Comment: @gnat you got a point, sorry

Comment: @CMW unlike the first link, the link you shared is informative, although it's not about domain names, but it's good to read, so if my question is going to be marked as a dupe and closed, it better be because of your link, not the first one

Comment: @JoeStrazzere they'll know about my site anyway, as a programmer, they'll ask if I have a personal site so it's a plus to put it there, the question is if I should add the `email@mydomain` or just use my gmail

Comment: @Fischer While it only talks about the first part of the e-mail address, I think the answers can also be applied to the domain part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, it's a matter of what image the reader is going to get. Since you're concerned, but haven't disclosed what the name of this "spooky" domain name is, I can only assume that it's something that you feel could potentially be an issue. A general rule of thumb I've heard is that if you have to ask, it's probably not appropriate (as with most rules of thumb, it's far from an absolute, of course. Only Sith deal in absolutes). Probably, your best bet is to run it by a neutral third party, and see what their reaction is to your email address. That could include us if you're willing to share it.

As a more general thing, using your own domain name is considered classy, but if your domain name could leave a bad impression, of course, that kind of overrules it.

As regards your later edit, I would probably have a negative reaction to a domain name such as "CodingHorror.com". If I were not familiar with the site in question, it would look flippant at best, and unintentionally self-revealing at worst.

Comment: I edited the question to add the details requested

Comment: {nods} It's the kind of domain that would leave me with a raised eyebrow, but not rule you out immediately. You will want to be prepared to get asked about it. It might ultimately become a plus if it leads to interesting anecdotes.